# Tuning tesseract command line to OCR prices

Tags: windows, ocr, tesseract

I have small images with prices in them like the following:

[image: Image $127.05]

But I am getting an empty output file when I try the command:

tesseract image.png output.txt

Are there any special commands I should use to OCR such small images like this?  Also, can I specify that the possible results will only be a dollar sign, a period, and the numbers 0-9?

I have tried the "letters" method by adding to a config file, but I haven't found any data on whether the dollar sign or period need to be escaped.  In any case, I am getting zero response with the simple version of the command above.

Answer (score 2):

What version of tesseract are you using? Using the following command:

tesseract image.png output -psm 8

I get this result.

$12705

Note that the dot is missing. You may be able to get the dot as well by pre-processing the image using a dilation algorithm.

Version info:
tesseract 3.03.00 (windows 7)
 leptonica-1.70 (Aug  5 2014, 21:29:11) [MSC v.1800 DLL Release x86]
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8c : libpng 1.4.3 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.8

Comment: I'll look for that version.  I'm still getting nothing, my version is, tesseract 3.02
 leptonica-1.68 (Mar 14 2011, 10:43:03) [MSC v.1500 LIB Release 32 bit]
  libgif 4.1.6 : libjpeg 8c : libpng 1.4.3 : libtiff 3.9.4 : zlib 1.2.5.

Comment: Where did you get that version.  The google code page only has 3.02

Comment: 3.0.3 is the release candidate for Tesseract. I only managed to compile Tesseract.exe and I copied this overwriting the existing version. When running the same command with 3.0.2 I do not get any output either. Please let me know if you have difficulty compiling 3.0.3 yourself.